# Pure javascript pixel manipulation with processing.js

Tags: processing.js

I would like to manipulate pixels with processing.js. I would like to do this in pure javascript but am having difficulties. The following simple case fails

```
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sketchProc(p){

// Configure page and init variables
function setup() {
    p.size(300, 300);
    console.log(p.pixels)
    p.background(100,200,100)
}

function draw() {
    p.loadPixels();
    for (var i = 0; i < 3000 ; i++) {
      p.pixels[i] = p.color(0,0,0)
    }
    p.updatePixels();
}

// Attach functions to processing object
    p.setup = setup;
    p.draw = draw;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1")
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc)
</script>
```

which (I believe) should convert the first 3000 pixels to black. Looking at the console.log for p.pixels I am wondering if this type of array access fails in pure javascript? Any suggestions welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you must Attach the functions directly to `p`:

```
function sketchProc(p){

    // Attach functions to processing object
    p.setup = function setup() {
        p.size(300, 300);
        console.log(p.pixels);
        p.background(100,200,100);
    };

    p.draw = function draw() {
        p.loadPixels();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3000 ; i++) {
          p.pixels[i] = p.color(0,0,0);
        }
        p.updatePixels();
    };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
```

Comment: It works! Great thanks very much. I cannot help but feel that something deeper is going on here that I don't understand though. Does the processing object need to own the functions themselves rather than just references?

Comment: In fact, it should work, because there is nothing wrong with your code, but it seems that the fact you use functions declaration in 'compile' style syntax (respectively `draw` and `setup`, creates conflicts with inner functions of processing.js, because if you name your functions `_setup` and `_draw` it will work.